# Get Horizontal distance between elements of a string

Tags: javascript, string, math

I have the following string:

```
var list = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456789!@$*+"
```

which representes the following matrix

[image]

I need too get the horizontal and vertical distance between 2 elements of the matrix, using the given string.

For example, the digit `b` has a vertical distance of 3 and a horizontal distance of 1 to the digit `1`.

I know I can get the vertical distance of 2 elements via the following formula:

```
verticalDistance = Math.round(Math.abs(list.indexOf(element1)-list.indexOf(element2)))/8
```

(I use `/8` because every 8 digits a there's a new "line")

But how can I get the horizontal distance? I have tried using:

```
horizontalDistance = Math.abs(list.indexOf(element1)-list.indexOf(element2))%8
```

But sometimes it works, and sometimes it doesn't.

Finally, I want to clarify that the horizontal distance cannot "wrap" in each line. What I mean by it is that, for example, the horizontal distance from `g` to `j` should be 5, because they are 5 positions apart, instead of 3, which you get by wrapping the end and the start of the matrix

Thank you for your time.

Comment: try `horizontalDistance = Math.abs(list.indexOf(element1)%8 - list.indexOf(element2)%8)`, if that works, you can probably figure out the total distance yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should obtain the remainder when divided by 8 to get the horizontal position of each element, then take the absolute delta.

```
Math.abs(list.indexOf(element1) % 8 - list.indexOf(element2) % 8)
```

The vertical distance calculation is also wrong. You should floor the result of dividing each index by 8 and then take the absolute delta.

```
Math.abs(Math.floor(list.indexOf(element1) / 8) - Math.floor(list.indexOf(element2) / 8))
```

The Manhattan distance is simply the sum of the horizontal and vertical distances.

Comment: @Unmitigated thanks, but it doesn't seem to work. For example the horizontal distance from "a" to "1" should be 2 and its vertical distance 3, yet the answer with your formula is 8 and 4, respectively.

Comment: @TheObands `'a'` is on index `0`, and `'1'` is on index `26`. `0%8=0`, `26%8=2`, `2-0=2` for the horizontal distance using that equation.

Comment: @KieranMoynihan you are right, I had an error in my code. The answer is correct!